# Serialize json value types with type data

Tags: c#, .net, json, serialization, json.net

I've almost solved my problem but missing the last piece...

I Have a list of object and I want to be able to add value types (that normaly will be serialized to strings) and get them back as the original type.
For example: Guids or custom value types.

This is a sample custom value type:

```
public struct ExtString
{
    private String Value
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public static implicit operator ExtString(String str)
    {
        return !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(str) ? new ExtString(str) : null;
    }

    public static implicit operator String(ExtString exStr)
    {
        return exStr.ToString();
    }

    public ExtString(String str)
    {
        this.Value = str;
    }

    public override String ToString()
    {
        return this.Value;
    }
}
```

This is the Custom converter:

```
public class CustomConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override Boolean CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType.IsValueType;
    }

    public override bool CanRead => false;

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        writer.WriteStartObject();

        writer.WritePropertyName("$type");
        writer.WriteValue(value.GetType().AssemblyQualifiedName);

        writer.WritePropertyName("$value");
        writer.WriteValue(value.ToString());

        writer.WriteEndObject();
    }
```

And here is the sample code for serializing / deserilizing:

```
    var jsonSerializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings()
    {
        TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All,
        Converters = new JsonConverter[]
        {
            new CustomConverter()
        }
    };

    var list = new List<Object>();

    list.Add(Guid.NewGuid());
    list.Add((ExtString)"Hello World");

    var ser = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(list, Formatting.Indented, jsonSerializerSettings);

    var deser = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(ser, jsonSerializerSettings);
```

This works almost all the way... Both the Guid and ExtString is serialized correct and the Guid is even deserialized with correct value (without special handling!), and the ExtString is created correct (on deserialize) but with the value null (constructor is called but str is null).

What am I missing? Why does it work for Guid?

Thanks.

Comment: What's JsonConverter? What namespace, library etc. does it come from?

Comment: Sorry. Json.Net (Newtonsoft)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you have to do is to specify the JSON property name for your `Value` property.

```
public struct ExtString
{
    [JsonProperty("$value")]
    private String Value
    {
     ...
```

---

### More in depth

The `Guid` mapping works because it is considered a [primitive type](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializationGuide.htm#PrimitiveTypes) and [`Json.Net`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) knows how to create a new instance and the parameter to pass to (using a `JsonPrimitiveContract`).

On the contrary, `ExtString` is resolved using a `JsonObjectContract` which calls the parameterless constructor of `ExtString` (it is there even if you don't declare it, because it's a value type) and then assigns the properties values to the corresponding json properties values. But the `ExtString` struct property name is `Value` while the JSON property name is `$value`. So a new istance of `ExtString` is created but the `Value` property remains null because there aren't properties with name `Value`. This is why, in your code, you have a new istance of `ExtString` with the `Value` property setted to `null`.

In the above solution I match the property name of the `ExtString` struct with the name of the property in the input JSON. After creating an instance of the `ExtString` struct, a mapping of the `$value` property will be done with success.

Another solution could be:

```
public struct ExtString
{
    private String Value
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    [JsonConstructor]
    public ExtString([JsonProperty("$value")] String str)
    {
        this.Value = str;
    }
```

In this case, the constructor with the `JsonConstructor` attribute will be used instead of the parameterless one. Note that the `str` parameter must be provided with the appropriate `JsonProperty` attribute which defines the property name (in the input JSON) whose value will be passed to the constructor. If you omit the `JsonProperty` attribute, `str` parameter will be null and so your `Value` property too.

The difference between the two solutions is on the *where* the `Value` property is assigned. In the first solution the property is assigned **after** creating the object, in the second solution the property is assigned by the **constructor**.

Think it in this way:

```
//First solution
var myObject = new ExtString();
myObject.Value = "Hello World";

//Second solution
var myObject = new ExtString("Hello World");
```

I think the first solution give you much more control setting the value because (modifing the setter method) your logic will be always called, no matter how you create the object or when you assign the value.

**Source**: a pleasant and immersive analysis of the [source code](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json).

I know, my English is very bad :)

Comment: Your english is fine :) Sounds reasonable and I understand the problem and even found another solution: writing the name of the construct var instead of $value when serializing. Unfortunally I've ran into another problem:
I'm also registering TypeConverters for handling conversions to and from string (needed for MVC model binding) and Json.Net is checking that someway and throws an error requesting these type to be serialized to and from strings! Am I thinking totally wrong here? All I want to do is to be able to ser/deserialize List<Object> with value type objects (eg. HtmlString).... :(

Comment: Closer :) : Found the JsonObjectAttribute that forces the object to be handled as an complext class when ser/deser and that solves it for my own classes, but how the heck do I decorate eg. Guid or HtmlString with this attribute? Or is there ,maybe another solution for system value types? Date works fine but I guess thats because of the builtin converter / handling....

Comment: I suggest you to take a look at the `ReadJson` method of `JsonConverter`. See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8031283/7772490. Using `ReadJson` you have the full controll of the deserialization. Hope it helps.

Comment: I'll see how you're thinking, but as far as I can see ReadJson won't work when serializing to Object because the CanConvert(Type objectType) will give you objectType == Object and all types can convert to Objects so you'll end up with a converter that needs to handle all types! Please tell me I'm wrong because this will solve a lot :) !

Comment: In `CanConvert` method, you  can check the current type of the object, not if the type can convert to another type. Try putting `return objectType.IsValueType || objectType == typeof(object);` in `CanConvert` method and then, in the `ReadJson` method, use `JObject obj = JObject.Load(reader);`. The `ReadJson` method should get called only with objects and not List<object>. So you can access to `$type` and `$value` using `obj["$type"]` and `obj["$value"]`.

Comment: Yes I now. But then I have to handle ALL conversions to Object (not only eg Guid and HtmlString) because when CanConvert is called I have no clue if it’s a type I want to hande or not, and when ReadJson is called it’s to late to cancel and let another converter kick in... right?